# Learnyounode tutorial help "My First IO"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do the learn you node tutorials from node school. But I'm getting the following error when I try to run the third exercise.

[image]

And my code is as follows

```html
var fs = require('fs');

var path = process.argv[2];

var str = fs.readFileSync(path).toString();

var arr = str.split('\n');

var num = arr.length;

console.log(num);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to put some quotes `"` around the path when you call the command?

Comment: Yes I did. Still no luck

Comment: try `learnyounode run program.js` without `path` specified

Comment: Might be that the path is at index 3: `process.argv[3];`

Comment: As @DavinTryon mentioned, and according to https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv the index shall be three. The other thing is, that all `process.argv` is a array of `string` always, that means your error indicates that something else is wrong. Uninitialised variable perhaps?

Comment: Try to put `console.log(process.argv)` after the first line and see how does the arguments array look like.

Comment: [ 'node',
  'E:\\Projects\\learnyounode\\program.js',
  'E:\\Projects\\learnyounode\\1.txt' ]

Comment: @DavinTryon according to the above output it should be at index 2 right?

Comment: @TAB yes, looks that way. :) puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs')

const contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2])
const lines = contents.toString().split('\n').length - 1
console.log(lines)
```

Note that the test
  **file does not have a newline character ('\n') at the end of the last line**,
  so using this method you'll end up with an array that has one more element
  than the number of newlines.